# The sentence as a case frame or a semantic model

Tags: syntax

I am now studying Deep and Surface Grammar and I can't understand any particular differences in representation of the sentence as a case frame (Ch. Fillmore's theory) or a semantic model (W. Chafe). Could anyone throw light on it somehow?

Comment: There's not a big difference. As long as the immediate constituents are clearly identified, it doesn't matter a lot which one you use, unless you have a particular analytic task in mind. Case is better for grammatical relations, and semantic models for bigger-scale relations. No single representation can possibly include all the information; what each does is highlight some relations in the hope that they are the crucial variables in a given situation. Then they try to see what kinds of predictions they lead to.

Comment: [Fillmore, Kay, and O'Connor 1968](http://lingo.stanford.edu/sag/papers/fillmore%2B88.pdf) is probably the best example of application of the method to a particular situation.